# Header, Footer, Left and Right side Template in JSP

Tags: java, css, jsp, templates

Developing a WebPage with Footer, Header and Left column.
 Below is `main.jsp` code

```
<table>
    <tr valign='top'><td><%@include file='leftside.jsp'%></td>
    <td><table>
    <tr><td><%@include file='header.jsp'%></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
    <tr><td><%@include file='footer.jsp'%></td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `leftside.jsp` code is below

```
<body bgcolor=blue>
Leftside
</body>
```

On running `main.jsp`, I only get the text as Leftside. The background color of blue is not displayed. Am i missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: replace `body` by `div`

Comment: Use <body bgcolor="blue">

Comment: Designing with a table? I believe this is considered bad practice these days. Anyway, remember that the whole thing after the include is considered one HTML document. You are not supposed to have `<body>` tags except the main body.

Comment: Replacing Body by Div tag in leftside.jsp worked. Using bgcolor="blue" had no effect.  thnks

Comment: Tiles and Sitemesh are perfectly good java libraries for templating. Use one of these. https://tiles.apache.org/ and http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh3/SiteMesh+3+Overview

Answer (score 0):

Please use the apostrophes `""` and it will work fine

```
<body bgcolor="blue">
Leftside
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 <body style="background-color:blue;">
```

Or with adding the apostrophes `"blue"`:

```
 <body bgcolor="blue">
```

Instead this:

```
<body bgcolor=blue>
```